# Remove languages from installer ISO

Tags: system-installation, iso

I need to make an ubuntu installer that only shows 2 languages (in my case, English and Bahasa Indonesia).

What file in the installer ISO do I need to modify to do this?

So it is clear what I mean, see:

[image]

Comment: For the screenshot, you can upload it somewhere else, and paste the link back here. (Don't forget you can [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/663168/edit) your question to update it.)

Comment: Take a look at [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization).

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate. Before shooting from the hip, *read* the message and understand the problem being asked.